# Проверка правильного количества скобок в тексте

Tags: c#

Как проверить что в тексте каждый '(' закрыт ')'?

Comment: используйте стек

Comment: Кейворды для гугления "c# balanced parentheses"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для одного типа скобочек

```
public bool IsValid(string s)
{
    var count = 0;
    foreach (var c in s)
    {
        if (c == '(')
            count++;

        if (c == ')')
        {
            if (count == 0) return false;
            count--;
        }       
    }
    return count == 0;
}
```

Для разных типов скобочек

```
public bool IsValid2(string s)
{
    var stack = new Stack<char>();  
    foreach (var c in s)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case '{':
            case '(':
            case '[':
                stack.Push(c);
                break;

            case '}':
                if (stack.Count == 0) return false;
                if (stack.Pop() != '{') return false;
                break;
            case ']':
                if (stack.Count == 0) return false;
                if (stack.Pop() != '[') return false;
                break;
            case ')':
                if (stack.Count == 0) return false;
                if (stack.Pop() != '(') return false;
                break;
        }
    }   
    return stack.Count == 0;
}
```

Comment: Еще можно использовать default и функцию, возвращающую скобку, обратную данной.

Comment: @МаксимФисман можно, но есть ли смысл?

Comment: switch-case будет выглядеть попривлекательней :)

Comment: @МаксимФисман ну хз, добавлять целую функцию, чтобы 5 строчек сэкономить - это просто усложнит код. Вот было бы у меня не 3 типа скобочек, а 23, то да, тут точно был бы смысл.

Answer (score -1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = "text ( hello) no me(1)-(2)-(3)-(4-(5)-6)";

            Console.WriteLine(All(test));


            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static bool All(string h)
        {
            return h.Where(v => v == '(').Count() == h.Where(v => v == ')').Count();
        }
```

Comment: `")))) как эта строка отработает с вашим решением? (((("`

Comment: не знаю все может быть