# Проверка правильности кода на Си(используя стек)

Tags: c, алгоритм, стек, проверка

помогите с таким заданием: в файл input получаем любой листинг кода, программа проверяет если есть открывающая скобка, кладёт её в стек и поднимает указатель, встречая закрывающую скобку того же вида, опускает указатель. В итоге: если стек в 0, то есть все скобки на месте, то код печатается в файл output, иначе выдаёт ошибку.

Не знаю правильно ли начал делать, ошибка в том что на данный момент он всегда выводит ошибку даже если все скобки в исходном листинге на месте.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "main.h"
#include <assert.h>

int main(void)
{
    Stack_t stack;
    stack.size = 0;
    read_input(&stack);

    getch();
    return 0;
}

void push(Stack_t *stack, const T value) // добавление в стек
{
    if (stack->size >= STACK_MAX_SIZE) // если размер стека больше или равен макс размеру, завершаем программу
    {
        exit(STACK_OVERFLOW);
    }

    stack->data[stack->size] = value;
    stack->size++;
}

T pop(Stack_t *stack) // извлечение из стека
{
    if (stack->size == 0)
    {
        exit(STACK_UNDERFLOW);
    }

    stack->size--;
    return stack->data[stack->size];
}

T peek(Stack_t *stack) // возвращение того что лежит в верхушкt стека без удаления оттуда.
{
    if (stack->size == 0)
    {
        exit(STACK_UNDERFLOW);
    }


    return stack->data[stack->size - 1];
}

void print_stack_value(const T value) // печать значения в стеке
{
    printf("%d\n", value);
}

void read_input(Stack_t *stack)
{
    char *file_loc1 = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\source\\NikitaSheffLessonsC\\C_Lesson18 Homework\\input.c";
    char *file_loc2 = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\source\\NikitaSheffLessonsC\\C_Lesson18 Homework\\output.c";
    char *input = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
    FILE *fptr1;
    int i = 0;

    fptr1 = fopen(file_loc1, "r");

    assert(fptr1 != NULL);

    while(input[i] != EOF)
    {
        switch(input[i])
        {
            case '(':
            {
                push(&stack, input[i]);

            }
            case ')':
            {
                if(peek(&stack) == '(')
                {
                    pop(&stack);

                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }

            }
            case '[':
            {
                push(&stack, input[i]);

            }
            case ']':
            {
                if(peek(&stack) == '[')
                {
                    pop(&stack);

                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            case '{':
            {
                push(&stack, input[i]);

            }
            case '}':
            {
                if(peek(&stack) == '{')
                {
                    pop(&stack);

                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            default:
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }

void print_stack(const Stack_t *stack, void(*print_stack_value)(const T)) // печать всего стека
{
    int i, len = stack->size - 1;
    printf("stack %d > ", stack->size);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        print_stack_value(stack->data[i]);
        printf(" | ");
    }

    if (stack->size != 0)
    {
        print_stack_value(stack->data[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Код из заголовочного файла:

```
#pragma once

#define STACK_MAX_SIZE 20 // макс размер стека
#define STACK_OVERFLOW -100 // что бы не выйти за пределы стека
#define STACK_UNDERFLOW -101 // 

typedef int T;

typedef struct Stack_tag
{
    T data[STACK_MAX_SIZE];
    size_t size;
}Stack_t;

void push(Stack_t *stack, const T value);

T pop(Stack_t *stack);

T peek(Stack_t *stack);

void print_stack_value(const T value);

void print_stack(const Stack_t *stack, void(*print_stack_value)(const T));

void read_input(Stack_t *stack);
```

UPD: на данный момент код выглядит так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "main.h"
#include <assert.h>

int main(void)
{
    Stack_t stack;
    stack.size = 0;
    read_buffer(stack);

    getch();
    return 0;
}

void push(Stack_t *stack, const T value) // добавление в стек
{
    if (stack->size >= STACK_MAX_SIZE) // если размер стека больше или равен макс размеру, завершаем программу
    {
        exit(STACK_OVERFLOW);
    }

    stack->data[stack->size] = value;
    stack->size++;
}

T pop(Stack_t *stack) // извлечение из стека
{
    if (stack->size == 0)
    {
        exit(STACK_UNDERFLOW);
    }

    stack->size--;
    return stack->data[stack->size];
}

T peek(Stack_t *stack) // возвращение того что лежит в верхушкt стека без удаления оттуда.
{
    if (stack->size == 0)
    {
        exit(STACK_UNDERFLOW);
    }


    return stack->data[stack->size - 1];
}

void print_stack_value(const T value) // печать значения в стеке
{
    printf("%d\n", value);
}

void read_buffer(Stack_t *stack)
{
    char *file_loc1 = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\source\\NikitaSheffLessonsC\\C_Lesson18 Homework\\input.c";
    char *file_loc2 = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\source\\NikitaSheffLessonsC\\C_Lesson18 Homework\\output.c";
    FILE *fptr1;
    int i = 0;
    long lSize;
    char * buffer;
    size_t result;

    fptr1 = fopen(file_loc1, "rb");
    if (fptr1==NULL) {fputs ("File error",stderr); exit (1);}

    fseek (fptr1 , 0 , SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell (fptr1);
    rewind (fptr1);

    printf("File size = %d\n", lSize);

    buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize);
    if (buffer == NULL) {fputs ("Memory error",stderr); exit (2);}

    result = fread (buffer,1,lSize,fptr1);
    if (result != lSize) {fputs ("Reading error",stderr); exit (3);}

    printf("Stack size = %d\n", stack->size);

    for(i = 0; i <= lSize; i++)
    {
        switch(buffer[i])
        {
            case '(':
            case '[':
            case '{':
            {
                push(&stack, buffer[i]);
                break;
            }

            case ')':
            case ']':
            case '}':
            {
                if(peek(&stack) == '(' || peek(&stack) == '[' || peek(&stack) == '{')
                {
                    pop(&stack);
                }
                break;
            }

            default:
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    buffer[i] = 0;

    fclose(fptr1);


    fptr1 = fopen(file_loc2, "w");

    assert(fptr1 != NULL);


    printf("Stack size = %d\n", stack->size);

    if((stack->size) == 0)
    {
        int i = 0;

        while(buffer[i] != EOF && i < lSize)
        {
            fputc(buffer[i], fptr1);
            i++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("error, bad code");
    }


    printf("Stack size = %d\n", stack->size);

    fclose(fptr1);

    free (buffer);
}

void print_stack(const Stack_t *stack, void(*print_stack_value)(const T)) // печать всего стека
{
    int i, len = stack->size - 1;
    printf("stack %d > ", stack->size);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        print_stack_value(stack->data[i]);
        printf(" | ");
    }

    if (stack->size != 0)
    {
        print_stack_value(stack->data[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

не понимаю как и почему stack->size равен 0 всегда, хотя если в файле инпута будет не хватать скобки то значение будет другим, следовательно должна быть ошибка а не печать кода в файл.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проверка правильного количества скобок в тексте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/935260/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1):

Как минимум вы намудрили с кодом видв

```
if(input[i] == '[')
{
    push(&stack, input[i]);
    stack->size++;
    if(input[i] == ']')
```

Ведт если `input[i] == '['`, то ветвь `if(input[i] == ']')` никогда не будет выполнена, так что со стека у вас ничего не снимается.

И еще - по вашей задумке последовательность скобок  типа `({[)}]` получается правильной - вы же не проверяете, что было в стеке (впрочем, вы вообще не обрабатываете закрывающие скобки).

Comment: а да, ошибку заметил, благодарю, не подскажите как вообще примерно это должно выглядеть в нормальном виде? и в идеале что бы проверка правильной последовательности тоже работала, что-то никак не допру, учусь только)

Comment: Сделайте через switch для каждого считываемого символа (default для всех, кроме скобок). Если это открывающая скобка - вносите ее в стек, если закрывающая - смотрите, что на вершине стека. Если соответствующая открывающая - снимайте со стека, если не соответствующая или стек пуст - выводите сообщение об ошибке и заканчивайте работу. По окончании работы смотрите, пустой ли стек. Да, еще у вас `char *input = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));` выделяет место для одного символа, а вы пишете туда их много. Лучше читать по одному символу и писать сразу на вывод, а если ошибка - стереть выходной файл.

Comment: Сделал switch, ниже написал, примерно вроде того получается? кажется я опять что-то забыл там правда или накосячил где-то)

Answer (score 1):

Первая ошибка - это выделение памяти, в этой строчке выделяется один символ, а в итоги желательно хранить весть файл:

```
    char *input = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

Поэтому меняем это примерно на такой код - после открытия файла получаем всю длину файла, потом выделяем под него буфер и читаем весь файл туда вот пример:

```
/* fread example: read an entire file */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
    FILE * pFile;
    long lSize;
    char * buffer;
    size_t result;

    pFile = fopen ( "myfile.bin" , "rb" );
    if (pFile==NULL) {fputs ("File error",stderr); exit (1);}

    // obtain file size:
    fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell (pFile);
    rewind (pFile);

    // allocate memory to contain the whole file:
    buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize);
    if (buffer == NULL) {fputs ("Memory error",stderr); exit (2);}

    // copy the file into the buffer:
    result = fread (buffer,1,lSize,pFile);
    if (result != lSize) {fputs ("Reading error",stderr); exit (3);}

    /* the whole file is now loaded in the memory buffer. */

    // terminate
    fclose (pFile);
    free (buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

После чтения всего файла в буфер по буферу можно итерироваться с помощью цикла `for(...)`

Вторая ошибка - конструкция switch-case в Си должна выглядеть так:

```
switch (...)
{
case VALUE1:
    ...
    break;
case VALUE2:
    ...
    break;
...
case VALUEN:
    ...
    break;
default:
    break;
}
```

В вашем коде отсутствуют инструкции break между кейсами, что приведет к исполнению всех подряд начиная с того в которой провалимся по условию.

PS и не забываем освобождать выделенную память функцией `free(...)` когда она больше не нужна.

Comment: Исправил switch, добавил выделение буффера как вы написали, но похоже где-то накосячил, обновил код в вопросе, не подскажите в чём проблема?