# Как перевести и что значит "Check the sequence of brackets (matching, interleaving)"?

Tags: алгоритм, очередь, стек, перевод

У меня есть задание:

> To solve the tasks create your own classes (MyStack, MyQueue) and
> classes java.util to find other solutions (methods signature should
> coincide, for example, MyStack -> Stack - empty(), peek(), pop(),
> push(E item)).
>
> 1. The text is given
>
> - Print out the words and the same words in reverse
> - Check the sequence of brackets (matching, interleaving)

Совсем не понимаю о чем идет речь в пункте под второй звездочкой. Подскажите пожалуйста что это означает и где искать информацию, и о каких скобках в общем идет речь?

Comment: [Проверка правильного количества скобок в тексте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/935293/179763) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Check the sequence of brackets (matching, interleaving)

Проверьте [правильность] последовательности скобок (соответствие<sup>1</sup>, чередование<sup>2</sup>).

<sup>1</sup> - чтобы каждой открывающей скобке была соответствующая закрывающая. `(([)])` *в этом смыле* OK, а `)()` - нет.

<sup>2</sup> - чтобы скобки представляли собой вложенные отрезки - т.е. сначала шла открывающая, а потом закрывающая, и чтобы не было пересечений разных скобок - `(([]))` - так нормально, `(([)])` - так нет.

Answer (score 2):

Если не ошибаюсь, то во втором пункте под последовательностью скобок (их совпадением и чередованием) понимается некая последовательность такого вида: `[]{}()` или такого `[(())]`, в первом случае соблюдено совпадение, а во втором чередование. А такие варианты `(]` или `{[}]` - не верные. Но лучше увидеть текст из вашего задания, тогда возможно прояснится, что  от  вас хотят.

Comment: В том то и дело, что все, что у меня есть - это вот это задание. А текст там может быть абсолютно любой((( имеется ввиду, что он передан заранее и его не надо вводить с клавиатуры

Comment: Stack подразумевает последним зашёл - первым вышел, то есть если в него поместить текст: [abc], то на выходе получим ]cba[ , а нужно [cba], то есть соблюсти совпадение скобок

Comment: То есть, если выводятся скобки, нужно заменять скобку в стеке на противоположную?

Comment: @МарияЛинк *То есть, если выводятся скобки, нужно заменять скобку в стеке на противоположную?* Задание ничего не просит заменить, оно просит только проверить валидность последовательности скобок (видимо, на предмет нарушения соответствия и/или чередования). То есть тупо сообщить "всё окей", "нарушено соответствие", "нарушено чередование" или "нарушено вообще всё что можно" (кодом ошибки или текстовым сообщением).

Comment: В задании всё-таки подразумевается создать утилитарные классы, которые обеспечивают необходимую функциональность, то есть текст помещённый в класс на основе стека должен на выходе из него быть с корректным реверсом, то есть с совпадением и чередованием скобок. Иначе какой смысл указывать второй пункт в задании?