# Проверка правильности расстановки скобок без Стака, но не Оверфлова - Java

Tags: java

Ghbdtn, программист! В моем методе я хочу проверить правильность расстановки скобок в строке, которую передаю как параметр. Вот этот метод:

```
   public void naStos(String wyraz) {
        char otwierajacy = '(';
        char zamykajacy = ')';
        int counterOtwierajace = 0;
        int counterZamykajace = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i > wyraz.length(); i++) {
            if (wyraz.charAt(i) == otwierajacy) {
                counterOtwierajace++;
            }
            if (wyraz.charAt(i) == zamykajacy) {
                counterZamykajace++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(counterOtwierajace);
        System.out.println(counterZamykajace);
        if (counterOtwierajace == counterZamykajace) {
            System.out.println("Ok");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
```

И я действительно не понимаю почему на выходе  `counterOtwierajace` i `counterZamykajace`
у меня равны `0`, даже тогда, когда в строке которую я подаю как параметр, есть скобки...
Надеюсь программист, который лучше меня, подскажет мне, спасибо :)

Comment: У ответов на Ваши вопросы слева есть значок "галочка". Он там для Вас.

Comment: @Igor у меня в компиляторе это было даже желтым показано, ахаха, какой же я слепой, спасибо, поставил галочку Вам!

Comment: Имейте ввиду, ваш код не проверет правильность расстановки скобок, а только считает их количество. Для проверки смотрите [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/935293/179763)

Comment: @tym32167 я не хочу использовать ```stack```

Comment: @tym32167 хотя Вы и правы, когда я например напишу ```)2+2(*3``` программа скажет Ок :(

Comment: Вам и не нужно использовать стек, если у вас только один вид скобок. Ссылку что я вам дал почитайте.

Comment: @tym32167 очень странно что в том вопросе который Вы указали есть ошибка в решение, то есть ответ который набрал 6 галочек - неправильный, я говорю о первой части, когда там используют один вид скобок

Comment: Отпишите там что конкретно неправильно, какие у вас есть контр примеры

Comment: То есть смотрите, когда код будет каждый раз здесь ```if (c == '(') count++;```, то переменная ```count``` в этом месте всегда должна быть равна ```0```, но когда будет использована проверка ```if (count == 0) return false;```, то сразу же после нее счетчик будет умешьшен на единицу (```count--;```), и дальше он будет равен ```-1```, а как я уже упоминал ранее, в начале цикла он всегда должен быть равен ```0```, и что бы исправить код, я бы например написал после ```if (count == 0)``` следущее ```counter++```, что бы в начале цикла ```counter``` был равен ```0```

Comment: Пишите мой ник в вашем комменте плиз, а то мне не придет оповещение.

Comment: `когда код будет каждый раз здесь if (c == '(') count++;, то переменная count в этом месте всегда должна быть равна 0` - нет, не так. Пример `(1 + (1 + (1+4)*3)*2)`

Comment: Не надо предполагать что там будет чему равно, просто приведите пример строки, на котором тот алгоритм выдаст неверный результат.

Comment: @tym32167 (2+2) + 5)

Comment: Работает как надо - [картинка](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aUkO.png)

Comment: @tym32167 ```2 * (3.4 - (-7)/2)*(a-2)/(b-1)))```

Comment: [Аналогично](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nL9TD.png), лишние закрывающие скобки в конце, все работает как надо.

Comment: вот тут сами проверье алгоритм [онлайн](https://dotnetfiddle.net/p8qJjq)

Comment: @tym32167 ```2 * (3.4 - (-7)/2)*(a-2)/(b-1))``` выдает False, хотя все правильно написано

Comment: у вас последняя скобка лишняя в вашем выражении, потому и дает false

Comment: @tym32167 Уже разобрался, был не прав, спасибо!

Comment: На здоровье! Хорошо, что все решилось

Comment: @tym32167 хотя спрошу еще, почему когда я подаю в строке ```)(```, то ваш алгоритм показывает как бы False, что есть правильно, но если на листочке решить алгоритм то ```counter``` в конце будет равен нулю, и алгоритм должен был бы вернуть True

Comment: Счётчик counter показывает, сколько есть незакрытых скобок. Когда мой алгоритм видит закрывающую скобку, при этом counter равен 0, это означает, что для закрывающей скобки нет пары (то есть нет открывающей), и мы доходим до кода, который обрабатывает эту ситуацию здесь   `if (count == 0) return false;`

Comment: @tym32167 я написал в новом вопросе эту проблему у меня, то есть я написал точно такой же алгоритм как у Вас, но он не работает

Comment: Если мой алгоритм работает, а ваш нет, значит он не точно такой же :) а так как вашего кода я не вижу, то и сказать по нему ничего не могу.

Comment: @tym32167 вот здесь задал новый вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1305721/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-a%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код не заходит в цикл.

```
//i > wyraz.length()
i < wyraz.length()
```

Это условие *продолжения* цикла.