# Ошибка в aлгоритме правильности расстановки скобок - Java

Tags: java

у меня есть код с алгоритмом проверки правильности написания скобок одного вида, который я посмотрел здесь - [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/935260/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5/935293#935293), и я пытаюсь сделать то же в Джаве, но у меня получается другой результат в итоге.

```
    public void naStos (String wyraz) {
        boolean ok = true;
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < wyraz.length(); i++) {
            if (wyraz.charAt(i) == '(')
                counter++;
            if (wyraz.charAt(i) == ')') {
                if (counter == 0)
                    ok = false;
                counter--;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
        if (counter == 0)
            ok = true;
        if (ok) {
            System.out.println("Ok");
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bledne sparowanie nawiasow w wyrazeniu: " + wyraz);
        }
    }
```

Когда я ввожу например `(` то получаю Ок, почему так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

замените

```
if (counter == 0)
    ok = true;
```

на

```
if (counter != 0)
    ok = false;
```

Ваш флаг `ok` равен `true` изначально, потому нет смысла его ешё раз в `true` выставлять. Зато если вы где то его уже выставили в `false`, то ваш код перетирает сейчас это.

Answer (score 0):

Как минимум нужно заменить:

```
if (counter == 0)
    ok = true;
```

на

```
    ok = counter == 0;
```

Потому как сейчас у вас на `(` будет `counter == 1` то есть открыли скобку, но не закрыли, но при этом `ok == True`, а это не правильно.