# Почему выполняется условие if?

Tags: c#

Не могу понять, почему выполняется условие

```
if (st != '(' || st != '[' || st != '{' || 
    st != ')' || st != ']' || st != '}')
```

причем выполняется только на закрывающие скобки.
Вот полный код

```
static void CheckBrackets(string str)
        {
            Stack<char> stack = new Stack<char>();
            int count = 0;
            
            foreach (var st in str)
            {
                if (st == '(' || st == '[' || st == '{')
                {
                    stack.Push(st);
                    ++count;
                    continue;
                }

                if (st != '(' || st != '[' || st != '{' ||
                    st != ')' || st != ']' || st != '}')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("зашел сюда");
                    continue;
                }
                
                var peek = stack.Peek();

                if (peek == '(' && st == ')'
                    || peek == '{' && st == '}'
                    || peek == '[' && st == ']')
                {
                    stack.Pop();
                    ++count;
                    continue;
                }

                if (peek == '(' && st != ')'
                    || peek == '{' && st != '}'
                    || peek == '[' && st != ']')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(++count);
                    return;
                }
            }

            if (stack.Count != 0)
                Console.WriteLine(count);
            else Console.WriteLine("Success");
        }
```

[image: Скрин работы]

Comment: вольмем условие `if (st != 0 || st!=1)`, попробуйте подобрать значение st, при котором условие НЕ пройдет - не сможете, потому что любое число либо не равно 0 либо не равно 1, либо не равно ни 0 ни 1. Вот и у вас условие так написано, что при любом значении st оно пройдет.

Comment: [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/935293/179763)?

Comment: @tym32167, задача одна и та же, но вопросы же разные. Спасибо за комментарий, понял, в чем ошибка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (st != '(' && st != '[' && st != '{' && 
    st != ')' && st != ']' && st != '}')
```

или

```
if (!(st == '(' || st == '[' || st == '{' || 
    st == ')' || st == ']' || st == '}'))
```